# SUM the value based on the time and date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help for adding different time interval reads value for date.

Suppose in day they are 24 hours, and I want the sum of 4-8pm in one row and another i.e. 0-4pm and 9pm 12 am in one row.

I was using below query :

```
SELECT
 ennt_date,
 CASE
  WHEN to_number(TO_CHAR(dta.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS'),'sssss')/60 >= 960
  AND  to_number(TO_CHAR(dta.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS'),'sssss') /60 <= 
 1200
 THEN   (reads)
 ELSE   (reads)
 END 
from MD_data
group by ennt_date
```

getting error saying:

> case is not group by function

Comment: The simplest way to solve the error is to add the CASE block to the GROUP BY clause : group by ennt_date, CASE WHEN to_number(TO_CHAR(dta.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS'),'sssss')/60 >= 960...

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  You can adjust the hhGroup time ranges per your needs.  I was unclear as to whether the 4pm-8pm went thru 7:59 (8pm) or thru 8:59(9pm)

```
SELECT ennt_date
       ,hhGroup
       ,Count(1) as cnt
FROM   
    (Select 
        ennt_date
        ,CAST( dta.end_time as time) as tm
        ,DATEPART(HH, dta.end_time ) as hh
        ,CASE When DATEPART(HH, dta.end_time ) < 16 Then '0am-4pm'
              When DATEPART(HH, dta.end_time ) < 20 Then '4pm-8pm'
              When DATEPART(HH, dta.end_time ) < 21 Then '8pm-9pm'
              When DATEPART(HH, dta.end_time ) < 24 Then '9pm-mid'
         END as hhGroup
     From md_data
    ) as mm
GROUP  BY ennt_date, hhGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the day in 4-hour segments and sum each one separately:

```
with
x as (
  select
    (extract(hour from end_time) div 4) * 4 as fragment,
    reads
  from md_data
)
select
  fragment,
  sum(reads)
from x
group fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample results would help, but I think you want:

```
SELECT trunc(ennt_date),
       ( ceil( extract(hour from ennt_date) / 4.0) * 4 - 4 ) as hour,
       SUM(reads)
from MD_data
group by trunc(ennt_date),
         ceil( extract(hour from ennt_date) / 4.0);
```